# How to access a hash defined in a model in a test fixture file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Jobs model with a `status_id` attribute. I have the following hash defined in the model that represents the attribute,

```
  JOB_STATUS = {
    new: 10,
    scheduled: 20,
    in_progress: 30,
    complete: 40,
    declined: 50,
    cancelled: 60,
  }
```

In my fixture file, `jobs.yml`, I would like to use the hash as follows

```
one:
  status_id: Job::JOB_STATUS[:scheduled]
  ... other model attributes
```

When I run my tests, `status_id` is always set to zero in the test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try interpolating the value in yml

```
one:
  status_id: <%= Job::JOB_STATUS[:scheduled] %>
  ... other model attributes
```

This should do

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stub in the value:

```
allow(Job).to receive(:JOB_STATUS).and_return ( JOB_STATUS = {
  new: 10,
  scheduled: 20,
  in_progress: 30,
  complete: 40,
  declined: 50,
  cancelled: 60,
} )
```

Comment: If I do that I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method allow for #<Class:0x36b7438>`

Comment: Sorry I only know the 'allow' syntax, are you using RSpec? If not there should be an equivalent method to stub in the value you need